# how to calculate the intersection area of two circles in shiny or R code

Tags: r, statistics, shiny

Anyone has shiny code or R code about how to calculate the intersection area of two circles?

## UI

```r
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
   # Application title
   titlePanel("Choose your probability"),
   # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
   sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
         sliderInput("radius",
                     "Probability of A",
                     min = 0,
                     max = 0.4,
                     value = 0.2),
         sliderInput("radius2",
                     "Probability of B",
                     min = 0,
                     max = 0.4,
                     value = 0.2)
      ),
      mainPanel(
         plotOutput("distPlot")
      )
   )
)
```

## Server

```r
library(shiny)
library(plotrix)
library(grid)

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {
   output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      isolate({
         plot(c(-1,1),c(-1,1), type = 'n')
      })
      draw.circle(-0.25,0,input$radius)
      draw.circle(0.25,0,input$radius2)
   })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can use this:

```
circle_intersection <- function(x1, y1, r1, x2, y2, r2){
  rr1 <- r1 * r1
  rr2 <- r2 * r2
  d <- sqrt((x2 - x1) * (x2 - x1) + (y2 - y1) * (y2 - y1))
  
  if (d > r2 + r1) # Circles do not overlap
  {
    return(0)
  } else if (d <= abs(r1 - r2) && r1 >= r2){ # Circle2 is completely inside circle1  
    return(pi*rr2)
  } else if (d <= abs(r1 - r2) && r1 < r2){ # Circle1 is completely inside circle2
    return(pi*rr1)
  } else { # Circles partially overlap
    phi <- (acos((rr1 + (d * d) - rr2) / (2 * r1 * d))) * 2
    theta <- (acos((rr2 + (d * d) - rr1) / (2 * r2 * d))) * 2
    area2 <- 0.5 * theta * rr2 - 0.5 * rr2 * sin(theta)
    area1 <- 0.5 * phi * rr1 - 0.5 * rr1 * sin(phi)
    return(area1 + area2)
  }
}

circle_intersection(-0.25,0,0.2,0.25,0,0.2)  # 0 (Circles do not overlap)
circle_intersection(-0.25,0,0.2,-0.25,0,0.1) # 0.031 (Circle2 is completely inside circle1)
circle_intersection(-0.25,0,0.1,-0.25,0,0.2) # 0.031 (Circle1 is completely inside circle2)
circle_intersection(-0.25,0,0.3,0.25,0,0.4)  # 0.06641675 (Circles partially overlap)
```

Comment: Isn't is "return(area1 + area2)" instead?

Comment: oops! And thanks!